# where is simple product module folder?

Tags: magento2, module, simple-product

From the Magento , I can tell by folder name
Module-bundle is for bundle products
Module-configurable-product for configurable product

so what about the simple product? I can't find where it is, I want to make some change on it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This path is simple product module `vendor\magento\module-catalog` and you create the custom theme override you theme like :- `Vendor_Name\Theme_Name\Magento_Catalog`

After you override must be run this command :-

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento c:f
```

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

You want `module-catalog` and in your custom theme `Magento_Catalog`